# Lan for work, wifi for gaming simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan, gaming

Windows 7 based machine, connected to the corporate network but via LAN cable but my question is is it possible to setup so that all the work related traffic gets routed trough the corporate network (LAN adapter) and gaming data to go trough a separate wireless Internet that machine is also connected to (Wireless adapter)? I appreciate all the help anyone can provide on this

Comment: You really need to run this through your corporate network guys. This will open your corporate network to security problems, and completely bypass the network security and policies. Having a connection to the Internet, bypassing your corporate firewall, is how Target got hacked, and it cost Target a lot of money. In some companies, in some jurisdictions, you would not only get fired, but could be up for criminal prosecution.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for the reminder, i am aware of it but  did not give much thought as this is one of those things i want to try to see if i can make it work but not for constant use, more of a curiosity really, one that could cause a lot of damage, again thank you for the reminder and i will be more careful. Regards

Comment: It could be tricky to set up, in my view - you could either tell the game to connect via a particular adapter, but probably the game has no such facility. Then at the routing level you could determine the IPs of servers the game is connecting to and try route that specific IP destination through wifi. Messy, if you ask me. If you can ran the game within a virtual machine this becmes quite easy - you tell the VM to only use that adapter (wifi) to connect to internet. It is also more secure due to VM isolation, but just as Ron said - your net admins won't like this either way.

Comment: Why are you playing games when you are supposed to be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have two different internet connections, it makes no sense using the same one.

Try using connectify application , if that doesn't work, there is an application called forcebindip, or you need a router which supports two incoming connections , or the final option is to buy a motherboard which supports two different network cards

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, the above two mentioned adapter are connected to separate networks, connectify is a simple hotspot application but the forcebindip is the one that might do the trick, tnx for the help

Comment: @MiroslavCojic i gave you a +1 to nullify your -1 because i think it was unfair

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer: you don't.**

However, I cannot definitively give that answer without more information. Is this machine in your office (I'm assuming, given the ethernet connection)? If it is, consider this:

The wifi you are going to be connecting to is *probably* managed by the company. I know that the company I work for has access logs for **all** access points, including guest wifi. In that case, they could absolutely look up traffic on both their LAN as well as their wireless access points. Piping network data through a different device won't help you in this situation since the final point of contact is still the company router.

If you are on a home machine, are you using a VPN to connect to your company network? If so, there are probably many more options out there, and piping network data through a wireless device WOULD work in this case, so long as the VPN operates solely off of your wired connection.

I am sorry I cannot suggest any applications to actually do this, but I hope that information helps you make a decision.